# ECHO not working correctly when executing via Windows batch file

Tags: oracle, batch-file, sqlplus

I am attempting to write a simple batch script that our users can use to redeploy a bit of code to an environment if that environment has been recently refreshed and wiped of our changes.

The script works great, but it is not quite logging the way I want it to. Do to restrictions with our deployment process (I am not the DBA, just a developer), we cannot include ECHO commands in the files.

To get around this, as part of my batch script, I create a [login.sql](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch2.htm#sthref414) file in the working directory that contains "SET ECHO ON" and "SPOOL file.log APPEND" commands. The goal was that this would be executed before the scripts and spool my output. However, while the SPOOL command seems to be working, the scripts' contents are not being ECHOed.

Here is the relevant code from the batch script:

```
:: Identify all files that begin with a number and end with .sql and write to a file.
dir /b *.sql | findstr /b "[0-9]" > ScriptsToImplement.txt

:: Show the user the files to be executed and confirm whether to proceed
echo The following scripts will be executed in %DB%:
for /f "delims=" %%i in (ScriptsToImplement.txt) do echo %%i
echo:
set /p PROCEED=Proceed with implementation? [y/n] ^>
if /i "%PROCEED%" NEQ "y" (goto :opt_to_terminate)

:: Build the user profile SQL file that will be executed after logging into SQLPlus
:: This allows for the spooling of the output without having the SPOOL command declared in the file.
echo SET ECHO ON >> login.sql
echo SPOOL %DB%~%FOLDER%~%DATESTAMP%.log APPEND >> login.sql

:: Go through the SQL files in the text file and execute them in the specified database.
for /f "delims=" %%i in (ScriptsToImplement.txt) do (
echo exit | sqlplus -L -S %DB_USER%/%DB_PASS%@%DB% @%%i
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 (@echo an error occurred with applying %%i; stopping further script execution... & pause & goto :terminate) else (@echo %%i was applied successfully) >> %DATESTAMP%_run_all.log
)
```

My understanding is since this is launching a separate SQL*Plus session with every separate script, it is calling the login.sql file every time and so should be using the SET ECHO ON command every time.

Comment: This is the line  `echo exit | sqlplus -L -S %DB_USER%/%DB_PASS%@%DB% @%%i` you are referring as "calling login.sql" every time. That is how it will work.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the scripts do not contain SET ECHO OFF?

Comment: @dbenham Yes, I wrote the scripts. The only non-DDL/DML they contain is an ALTER SESSION command.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using it in your BAT file(s), remember that `ECHO` is a command, not an environment variable. The command to turn on echo is `ECHO ON`. `SET ECHO ON` does not affect echo behavior. It returns *"Environment variable ECHO not defined"* instead.

Comment: SET ECHO ON is a SQL*Plus command. I am writing that command to my login.sql file expecting it to be executed before my script.